# Print character without system calls

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, qemu, osdev

I'm wondering how to print a character in assembly without `int 0x80` and other system calls. I am doing this for a kernel. I have a working print function, but I want to write one in assembly, so I better understand how it actually works w/o just compiling everything to assembly. I'm using *QEMU*. I'm new to assembly and have only been able to print strings using syscalls. I am using *NASM* assembler and I would like the output to be ELF32. This is pseudo-assembly of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
section .text
global _start
extern magic_print_function
_start:
      mov edx,1;length of buffer
      mov ecx,'c';character c to print
      ;somehow magically print the character without specifying stdout, maybe something like the VGA buffer?
      call magic_print_function
```

Comment: You can't. The only way to tell the kernel, "Hey -- do this" is via a system call/interrupt. And on x86, that `int 0x80`. Now in `nasm` and other assemblers, you can create *macros* to automate character printing. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin so I would have to do somethin in c to get it to the vga buffer?Why can't I do it in assembly?

Comment: That is the difference between *real-mode* and *protected-mode* computing. In old 16-bit DOS, etc, you had direct access to the video buffer. (and the rest of the system). Beginning with (I can't even remember), with the switch to protected mode computing, only the kernel has access to the video buffer (and most other hardware) and you are limited to making system calls to tell the kernel to do something. You can still do everything in assembler you can do in C, but both deal with the processor API via system interrupts.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin okay i'm making it for a kernel,so how would I do that

Comment: Exactly, you now deal with the processor *API* regardless what language you are writing code in. It all boils down to compiling your code into an executable that translates into the machine language for the API. Whether you do that in C or you do it in assembly, it will all boil down to system calls taking place to carry out your instructions. In C that is hidden from you, in assembly, you are responsible for them.

Comment: If the kernel is in protected mode then you can do it by writing directly to the video ram (like b8000 in text mode/page 0). If it is a real mode kernel then you can use the BIOS interrupts and/or write directly to video memory.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thank you

Comment: @MichaelPetch would I use out byte?

Comment: Assuming an EGA/VGA text mode every cell (location on the screen) is made up of 2 bytes (A word). One byte being the character to display, and the other byte the foreground and background attributes (color etc). This [OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Printing_To_Screen) page may help. This will work if developing a kernel, but don't expect a userland application in Linux to allow it. The video memory is protected by Linux, so attempting to write to it directly will cause a fault. If you write your own kernel, your kernel has complete access to the hardware and memory.

Comment: When running in Linux you make Syscalls (or int 0x80) to tell the Linux Kernel to do something on your behalf. So if writing to standard output requires a call through the kernel to output the characters on your behalf by updating video memory with the change and returning back to your program.

In Linux, the C Library which does sys_write and sys_read (including stdout and stdin) makes a call to the kernel under the hood.

Comment: I see the amendment to your question regarding QEMU. If you are in fact using QEMU, and you want ELF images, then may I ask if you are in fact  using a multiboot loader like GRUB? The legacy PC BIOS doesn't know anything about ELF32 format, but GRUB does support them.  GRUB will also place your program into protected mode (assuming you aren't chain loading)

Comment: A Stackoverflow user (Ciro Santilli) has created a collection of programs that print _Hello World_ . This particular project example creates a multiboot(GRUB) compliant ELF executable that writes directly to video memory. https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/tree/master/multiboot/hello-world . The Makefile will also launch QEMU for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, you say You don't want any c. That's a tad difficult, but I'm sure it's possible.

To start out, you want to set ax and dx equal to 0. Then start the stack off at 0. Then, you'll want to load the video memory into ax. The video memory starts at 0xb800. Then make es the same value as ax.

Load your message into a variable and put it into si. At this point, call a function that writes a string to the video memory. This function is made of of smaller functions that individually write characters and move the cursor one spot to the right.

Once you've got the code to write a string, hang it with a loop. that's incredibly simple:

```
loop:
    jmp loop
```

For more, try this
http://wiki.osdev.org/Babystep4